# How do I move files not accessed for a long time using a batch file?

Tags: windows, filesystems, batch, batch-file

I like to move files accessed for a long time. For instance: if I do not access some file by 7 days, it move to `old` sub-folder.

```
file1.txt    1 days         <keep>
file2.txt    2 days         <keep>
file3.txt    4 days         <keep>
file4.txt    7 days         <move to old>
file5.txt    10 days        <move to old>
```

Comment: robocopy can be used for that (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following Robocopy syntax

```
ROBOCOPY "C:\MyFiles" "C:\OldFiles" /move /minage:30 /s
```

In the above note `minage:30`

This will move everything older than 30 days

So, in your instance, you'll use

`minage:7`

```
ROBOCOPY "C:\MyFiles" "C:\OldFiles" /move /minage:7 /s
```

Your post isn't clear if you only want this to be targetting .txt files or not, if so then use

```
ROBOCOPY "C:\MyFiles\*.txt" "C:\OldFiles" /move /minage:7 /s
```

Then, you simply set this up to run every day from Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html). More precisely the following command should help. It is merely a template :). The command only moves all text files from "source" to "old" older than last week (03/23/2015)

```
ROBOCOPY C:\source\*.txt C:\old /MOVE /MINAGE:n = 20150323
```